# Is there any way to clip built objects into scenery objects?

Tags: fallout-4

I know I can use `tcl` to clip constructed objects together, but is there any way to clip constructed object into already existing world objects, such as the walls of the Castle?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very good tutorial on how to rebuild The Castle's walls.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJon8.jpg
Just follow it and it should work out.
As far as i know you can't clip into prebuilt world objects, there will be when the G.E.C.K comes out.

Comment: The image showed console controls, so am I right to assume it works anywhere?

Comment: It's work with all platforms, no worries.

Comment: Yeah, I've already done that. Not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm trying to install some doors in the open doorways.

Comment: Please type out the tutorial here. Links can go dead. That is probably why you get downvoted.

(And type out, not just copy paste it all, copyright infringement and all that).

Comment: If that tutorial uses console, it ain't working for [the consoles (ps4 and xbox)](http://ca.ign.com/articles/2015/11/23/bethesda-fallout-4-console-commands-not-available-on-playstation-4-xbox-one-not-recommended-on-pc)

Answer (score 1):

To place items whilst ignoring clipping issues, there's a rather simple technique:

- Place an object to act as a platform for the object to be clipped (small mats recommended), then place the object on top of this platform.
- Now select the platform and move it to the location desired; the object atop it will move with the selected object AND the boundaries of the platform are used for placing the object.
- Place your object where you like and remove the base object.

This technique at least works on the Xbox One using junk-fence gates. Using this technique I placed a junk gate through the wall in the castle.